# CookieManager.getInstance() crush for not doing CookieSyncManager::createInstance()

Tags: android, cookies, webview

I don't understand why I am getting this error:

> CookieSyncManager::createInstance() needs to be called before CookieSyncManager::getInstance()

In my code I am doing this:

```
CookieManager.getInstance().setCookie(url, "skip_interstitial=1");
```

I am not using CookieSyncManager anywhere.
Am I suppose to do CookieSyncManager.createInstance(Context) even though I am only using CookieManager?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**You must call** `CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);` **In Your  Respective Activity**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
```

Comment: Just to make sure, I am using CookieManager and not CookieSyncManager. Is that still the case? Also, I get this error only about 1 out of 100 times that I am using this activity...